# "While I was on holiday", "when I was on holiday" , "while on holiay", "when on holiday", "on holiday" or "during holiday"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which one of the following sentences sounds the most natural?

> 1. I visited a lot of new places while I was on holiday.
>
> 2.
>   I visited a lot of new places when I was on holiday.
>
> 3. I visited a lot of new places while on holiday.
> 4. I visited a lot of new places when on holiday.
> 5. I visited a lot of new places on holiday.
> 6. I visited a lot of new places during holiday.

I feel that grammatically all the sentences are correct, but I would like to know ones native English speakers would say.

Comment: You know we do not edit here. You can check easy of those individually by yourself. These kinds of questions really try one's patience.

Comment: Well, how do I check them? I thought if you don't know the answers to questions, this site is what it was made for. And if such questions try your patience, why don't you just ignore such questions

Comment: For example: you can google: //site:bbc.com  "while on holiday"//You search a specific site for the phrase. The BBC is a reputable site for English. Please note: holiday in this sense is British English. // Actually, there are rules for asking questions and they include your own efforts/research. You can read them under the Help tab,top right corner under the last icon on the page.

Comment: Also, you can search this site (ELL) in the Search box. OR: site.ell.stackexchange.com THE TERM

Comment: Thank you! I got it!